# Unable to locate DataContext of parent object

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, data-binding

I'm trying to make a `TabControl`, populated with few `UserControl`s each with a separate ViewModel.

I've declared it in my XAML like this:

```
<TabControl Margin="10,10,10,40" ItemsSource="{Binding Test}">
    <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" FontSize="16" Padding="5"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
</TabControl>
```

As you can see I'm trying to obtain the name of the tab through a property located in it's View Model:

```
public class GeneralTabViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set
        {
            _name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public GeneralTabViewModel()
    {
        Name = "Name";
    }

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

The View Model associated with the window that holds the `TabControl` is declared as follows:

```
public class SettingsViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<UserControl> Test { get; set; }

    public SettingsViewModel()
    {
        Test = new ObservableCollection<UserControl>
        {
            new GeneralTab(),
            new GeneralTab()
        };
    }
}
```

Building the program like this yields an empty Header for the 2 tabs.

How can I bind the `TextBlock`'s `Text` property to the `Name` property located in the View Model of the `UserControl`?

If I change the `ItemSource` type from `ObservableCollection<UserControl>` to `ObservableCollection<GeneralTabViewModel>` I will be able to access the property, but how am I going to visualize the `UserControl` than?

Comment: Share code of user control.

Comment: Your GeneralTab User control must implement Generaltabviewmodel. Bind name property there.

Comment: @GaurangDave Are you implying that my user control should be a view model and a user control at the same time?

Comment: If I understood correctly then your need is to put your user control in each tab item from Test collection in SettingsViewModel. Your Binding SettingsViewModel in your given xaml code then it can not access property of GeneralTabViewModel. 
You should put GeneralTab (usercontrol) code here with question.

Comment: @GaurangDave There's nothing in the UserControl's codebehind.

Comment: this is how it can not be achieved. You are binding wrong View Model. What your UserControl is about? I mean what UI element it has? Is it  tab item?

Answer (score 1):

It is wrong to have UserControls in your SettingsViewModel. It should instead have a collection of GeneralTabViewModels:

```
public class SettingsViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<GeneralTabViewModel> Test { get; }

    public SettingsViewModel()
    {
        Test = new ObservableCollection<GeneralTabViewModel>
        {
            new GeneralTabViewModel { Name = "Tab 1" },
            new GeneralTabViewModel { Name = "Tab 2" }
        };
    }
}
```

You would then use the UserControl in the ItemTemplate of your TabControl:

```
<TabControl Margin="10,10,10,40" ItemsSource="{Binding Test}">
    <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <GeneralTab TabName="{Binding Name}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
</TabControl>
```

In order to make ths work, it is important that GeneralTab does not explicitly set its DataContext property. It may look like this:

```
<UserControl x:Class="YourNamespace.GeneralTab" ...>
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock FontSize="16" Padding="5"
                   Text="{Binding TabName,
                          RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

with this dependency property in its code behind:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty TabNameProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(TabName), typeof(string), typeof(GeneralTab));

public string TabName
{
    get { return (string)GetValue(TabNameProperty); }
    set { SetValue(TabNameProperty, value); }
}
```